# Kullback-Leibler distance calculation for discrete distributions?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, posterior, kullback-leibler, distance-functions

I have the following model

$$N \sim Pois(\lambda) \\ 
n \sim Bin(N,p)$$

for which I calculate the posterior for the parameter $N$ as

$$\pi(N|n,p,\lambda) = \frac{f(n|N,p)\pi(N|\lambda)}{f(n|p,\lambda)}$$

My goal is to calculate the Kullback-Leibler distance between the posterior and prior, i.e. $KL = \sum \pi(N|n,p)log\frac{\pi(N|n,p,\lambda)}{\pi(N|\lambda)}$

---

$1)$The first step is to calculate the prior predictive $f(n|p,\lambda)$

$f(n|p,\lambda) = \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \binom{N}{n}p^{n}(1-p)^{N-n}\frac{\lambda^{N}e^{-\lambda}}{N!}$

However, for $N<n$ I believe the $\textit{Binomial}$ distribution would be meaningless, so I start the sum from $N=n,n+1,...

$f(n|p,\lambda) = \sum_{N=n}^{\infty} \binom{N}{n}p^{n}(1-p)^{N-n}\frac{\lambda^{N}e^{-\lambda}}{N!}$

Because, I do not know how to calculate it analytically, I calculate it numerically by generating a sequence of numbers $n,n+1,..., M$, where $M$ is a sufficiently large number that will make the $\textit{Poisson}$ prior zero (so I truncate the summation), and finally iteratively calculate the sum.

$2)$ Now that I have calculated (hope correctly) the prior predictive and I know all the terms of the posterior as functions of $N$, I can move forward to calculating numerically the $KL$ distance.

$$KL = \sum_{N=n}^{\infty} \pi(N|n,p)log\frac{\pi(N|n,p,\lambda)}{\pi(N|\lambda)}$$

I again simulate a large sequence of numbers $n,n+1,..., M$ for a sufficiently large $M$.

---

**Questions**:

$i)$ Is there a way to calculate analytically the prior predictive $f(n|p,\lambda)$? Or what I did is used in practice??

$ii)$ In the second step, there would be a problem when $N=M$ (or when $N$ starts getting unlikely values) because the $\textit{Poisson}$ prior would be zero, something that has to be avoided because it is on the denominator. Is there a way to alleviate that problem?

$iii)$ The ranges we conduct the summations are correct?? I thought that they should be different because in the prior predictive we take the sum over the range of prior beliefs (however, we take into account the value of $n$ which is somehow counterintuitive). Whereas in the $KL$ the summation should be over the values of the posterior range, I assume they coincide?

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, yes, you're right, the Binomial distribution doesn't make sense for $N < n$. More precisely, we can say that $f(n | N, p) = 0$ for $N < n$ (intuitively, you're saying that the probability of getting $n$ successes in $N$ tries is zero). You can then write your summation as you did, starting from $N = n$. Then, you can analytically compute the prior predictive distribution as follows:

$p(n | p, \lambda) = \sum_{N=n}^{\infty} f(n | N, p) \pi(N|\lambda) = \sum_{N=n}^{\infty} {N \choose n} p^n (1-p)^{N-n} \frac{\lambda^N}{N!} e^{-\lambda}$

$= \frac{(\lambda p)^n}{e^\lambda} \sum_{N=n}^\infty \frac{N!}{n! (N-n)!} \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^{N-n}}{N!} = \frac{(\lambda p)^n}{n!e^\lambda} \sum_{N=n}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^{N-n}}{(N-n)!}$

$= \frac{(\lambda p)^n}{n!e^\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^{k}}{k!} = \frac{(\lambda p)^n}{n!e^\lambda} e^{\lambda(1-p)} = \frac{(\lambda p)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda p}$

You can see that this is again a Poisson distribution, with parameter $\lambda p$. Note that this is similar to a conjugate prior, but a rare one, because usually in a Binomial likelihood $N$ is considered known and $p$ is the target of statistical inference.

I hope this helps answer your questions!

Comment: Never thought about that, really helpful!!!

Comment: Do you think that it would be possible to use the same argument when you have more than one binomial draw, i.e. when your likelihood is of the form $\prod_{i=1}^{M}\binom{N}{n_{i}}p^{n_{i}}(1-p)^{N-n_{i}}$?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. Your likelihood could become much more complex depending on the exact data generating process you have in mind. Could you describe that first, so we can see where that leads us?

Comment: Yes of course! There are $K$ occasions and for each one we sample $n_{k}$ individuals from a fixed population $N$. The occasions are independent. So, we can describe the observed data with the following likelihood $p(n_{1},n_{2},...n_{K}|N,p) = \prod_{k=1}^{K} Bin(n_{k};N,p)$.

Comment: Where because we work in a Bayesian framework we place a Poisson prior on $N$, you can regard the $p$ as know number because is out of interest

Comment: It seems I don't really understand your situation yet. When you sample individuals from a population, what exactly are you sampling? Why would a Binomial distribution be useful? What is "success" or "failure" in this case? Are you sure that you won't sample the same individual twice (hence it wouldn't be independent anymore)?

Comment: For example, we examine a particular area with $N$ individuals of a species. An observer goes to the middle of the area, and starts counting individuals, for a short period, say 15mins we denote this occasions as $k$. Success can be considered that an individual is counted or not $Bern(p)$, and then we aggregate all those counted individuals, and say what is the abundance of that species. We assume independence between the occasions $k=1,2,...,K$ and between the individuals, to derive the likelihood displayed on the previous comment.

Comment: This is quickly getting very far from my area of knowledge, so I don't think I'll be able to help you much more. Still, I think the binomial distribution might not be suitable here because it might be plausible that the "trials" are not independent (for example, if a group of animals move together as a family, then observing one makes it more likely to observe the others as well). On the other hand it may work as an approximation. In that case you could indeed see the observations as repeated draws from the same binomial distribution.

Comment: In that case, I don't think the algebra works out well because of the binomial coefficients. In the case of a single binomial observation, the $N!$ from the binomial coefficient gets canceled by the one in the Poisson prior. If you have multiple binomial coefficients you might not be able to get rid of those nasty terms. Unfortunately I don't have time to try to work out the algebra - perhaps you can use my derivation above to get you started on working this out. Good luck!